# SO_REUSEPORT with epoll and multiple process

Tags: c, linux, performance, sockets, epoll

In a nutshell, `SO_REUSEPORT` socket option allow to create multiple sockets on ip:port pair. For example, `program1` and `program2` both can call functions chain `socket()->bind()->listen()->accept()` for the same port and IP, and kernel scheduler will evenly distribute incoming connections between this two programs.

I assumed that with this option, you can get rid of the use of `fork()` for spawning additional workers and can simply run new program instance.

I wrote a simple epoll socket server, based on this logic, and test it with weighttp:

`weighttp -n 1000000 -c 1000 -t 4 http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

For two running instances the results is ~44000 RPS, for one running instance - near ~51000 RPS. I am very surprised with 7000 RPS differece.

After this test I add `fork()` before `listen()` and run one instance of server, so now it has the same logic that previous implementation - two process with epoll loop listening socket, but `socket()->bind()` called only once, before `fork()`, and second process receive it FD copy for `listen()` call.

I run tests again and it shows ~50000 RPS!

So, my question is very simple: what magic do `fork()` in this case and why it works faster than two independent process with it own `socket()`? Kernel do the same job for scheduling, I dont see any important difference.

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/694576

Comment: Iam read this answer, its not cover my question.

Comment: Did you enable `SO_REUSEPORT` before `bind()`ing the address in each of the processes? From some quick reading I don't think `SO_REUSEPORT` would make any difference if you do the `bind()` before forking off the threads. Each thread should `bind()` separately instead.

Comment: `setsockopt()` with `SO_REUSEPORT` and `bind()` are called only in parent, before `fork()`. Child do ony `listen()` after fork.

Comment: @Alex: In that case `SO_REUSEPORT` might not make any difference. My understanding is that you should create a separate `socket()` in each of the threads and bind them to the same port.

Comment: Also, you should post your app, yeah. :)

Comment: And what exactly is "*RPS*", "*reads-per-.second*"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this comment to flag question as answered: due to my research, internal OS scheduler is far from optimal and depends on hardware. Better is to use user-land scheduler.

Comment: I think you create epoll descriptor before calling fork() which means you actually have a single epoll() list and a single socket kernel buffer. And everything else is consistent with contention overhead.